# Custom 403 Page for Google Storage Hosted Site?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

It *is* possible to set a custom 404 page on a GCS hosted static site with:

`gsutil web set [-m <main_page_suffix>] [-e <error_page>] gs://<bucket_name>`

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web#set-options

**So, is it possible to set a custom 403 page?**

We're sending users first to a `redirect.html` which then check their permissions to send them to `index.html`.

I'd like to leave them with a useful message like "remember to login" rather than a 403 error which likely means nothing to them.

Comment: No, and this is because the authentication is done even before you reach the objects in the bucket.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO, does the comment above address your concern?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do this. However the solution here is to host and serve your file from App Engine standard and not from Cloud Storage.

On App Engine standard, define [only static files in the handlers sections](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/serving-static-files?tab=python). Like that, you will serve file for free (no App Engine instance spawn to serve your files.

On top of App ENgine standard, you must [activate IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authenticate-users-google-accounts). IAP create a proxy that first check the authentication and then serve the static page. If you aren't authenticated, you are redirected to a login page automatically (and you can customize it if you want). However, if you haven't the permission (401 error), you can't have a custom page for that.

Bonus: I prefer to serve the content with App Engine because I can version my code. Each release is in a version and it's easy to roll out and roll back in those condition. That is not the case with Cloud Storage.